How can I plot X+Y+label values in a Google Sheets scatter chart?
I have three columns in a Google Sheet, containing a name and X/Y coordinates. I want to create a graph where each row of my data gets one dot on the graph, the location of the dot in the graph comes from the X/Y coordinates, and the dot is labeled (ideally only on hover or click) with the name.
Example data:
Center,0,0
West,-5,0
East,5,0
North,0,5
South,0,-5


A chart with the following settings will plot the points as desired but with no apparent way to associate the name:

Chart Type: Scatter Chart
Data Range: a range covering at least the X and Y coordinate columns
X-Axis: The X column from the Data Range
Series: The Y column from the Data Range
Use Column X as Labels: checked

